# Can you add two numbers, as if they were positives, even if they may be negative

Tags: c#

Most of this info isn't needed to answer my question, I am including it, in case someone knows of a much easier way to do this, my question is at the end.

I have an X and Y Vector, that I am using is a path for a travelling ball.  When that ball hits a wall, lets say the top wall, it will bounce in the negative direction, this is easy enough.  But if it hits an angled wall, I can easily enough calculate the one direction and I want to add the rest of the force to the other.  Think of it as Pong or Minigolf.

Example.

A ball is travelling 5,10  that means for every 5 pixels it travels right it travels down 10.
When it hits the bottom, I will multiply the Y axis by -1  making it 5,-10

But if I hit a 45 degree angle instead some of that force would be transferred into the X direction. Either way.

**Question:**
I need to make X+Y total 15,  if one of them is negative I need it to be considered as positive.

```
-10+5 = 15
-5+10 = 15  
 5+10 = 15
-5+-10 = 15
```

I know I could convert them all to positive first then compare but that seems bulky.

Comment: If you're trying to make sure the _speed_ is the same after the reflection, you don't want `(positive x) + (positive y)` to be constant. You want `x*x + y*y` to be constant.

Comment: agreed, I am only using the coordinates as a direction, I have a speed factor involved as well.  You may be correct in that my numbers wont work, and in that case I will deal with it at the time.  I am not going commercial, I am just working on some concepts, and wall bouncing is not one of them

Comment: I can't believe someone marked me down and didn't even have the guts to leave a comment!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `Math.Abs` function to turn both -15 and +15 into +15:

```
var a = -10;
var b = 5;

Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(a) + Math.Abs(b))
```

Comment: Perfect that's what I was looking for, gotta wait out the clock now, 9 minutes I will mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you are looking for the length of the vector. The length is calculated like this:

```
Math.Sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
```

With the length of the vector you can compare vectors with other directions as well, for example (2, 11) is of the same length as (5, 10).